# Howto search In-Memory table records by REST API?

Tags: wso2, siddhi, wso2-das, wso2-cep

We are using WSO2 DAS. We defined table(in-memory table) by siddhi, and we want to use DAS REST API to search this table's record, we use

curl -k -XGET 'https://localhost:9443/analytics/table_exists?table=table1' -H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4="

but the response is that the table does not exist.

How we can search the in-memory table records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siddhi in memory tables cannot be accessed by DAS REST API, so you have to persist content in the memory to a persistant stream which will store in a event table.